# Link a page that I have created at views

Tags: angularjs, hyperlink, mean-stack

I am editing an app developed using MEAN framework. I have footer.html from views, and I have just put a link like:

```
<li><a href="#!/privacy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
```

Then I have created a html page inside views folder, named privacy.html.

When I click on the footer it does show up. It works well with the other link and page there, which is FAQ. What I am doing it wrong? Is there anything else I need to code or use controller to get the new page shown.

Comment: could you please add .html extension :
<li><a href="#!/privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>

Comment: Try <li><a href="#privacy">Privacy Policy</a></li>

Comment: Everyone here can only guess without more information. It's not clear exactly what's wrong, nor can we tell if you're using routes and how they're set up. Throw relevant code into a jsfiddle and link it in your question.

Comment: I just saw that I needed to do the right route. Now it works, That was the problem. Sorry about not providing you more information, but I did not know how this worked.

Comment: you need to make sure to add 'state' which shows where your template file is for that 'state'. If you are using http://mean.io then I would suggest making your own package and seeing how it is done or to look in the system package under the public/routes